# ¿Como convertir un struct * a una variable tipo const *char?

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy utilizando una librería de terceros llamada "graphics" con la que estoy intentado mostrar una estructura de datos de tipo árbol binario de manera gráfica, mi problema es que existe una función llamada:

```
outtextxy(posicionX,posicionY,const *char)
```

y yo tengo un struct hecho de esta manera:

```
struct ABB {
   int dato;
   ABB *der;
   ABB *izq;
   ABB *padre;
}*arbol;
```

Los datos se ingresan normalmente en el struct pero no puedo mostrarlos en la función por no ser de tipo const *char...
Lo que quiero hacer es convertir esos datos en el struct en una variable const *char para que me permita ingresarlos en la función outtextxy pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo! Espero me puedan ayudar con esto!!!

Aqui muestro el código de la función outtextxy

```
void outtextxy(int x, int y, char *textstring){
 HDC hDC = BGI__GetWinbgiDC( );
WindowData* pWndData = BGI__GetWindowDataPtr( );

// check alignment
if (pWndData->alignment != TA_NOUPDATECP)
{
pWndData->alignment = TA_NOUPDATECP;
set_align(pWndData);
}

TextOut(hDC, x, y, (LPCTSTR)textstring, strlen(textstring));
BGI__ReleaseWinbgiDC( );

RefreshWindow( NULL );
// Todo: Change to refresh only the needed part.}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar la definición de `outtextxy`?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para añadir el contenido... los comentarios son para aclarar dudas pero si la pregunta está incompleta la forma de completarla es editándola. Para ello usa el enlace [edit] que se encuentra debajo de las etiquetas de la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Lo que recibe la función `outtextxy` es una cadena de texto. Para mostrar los valores de tu struct primero deberías generar una cadena de texto con lo que quieras mostrar. Podés hacer algo así:

```
struct ABB *nodo; // el puntero al nodo que querés mostrar
int x, y; // la posición donde querés escribir
char buffer[1024] = "";
sprintf(buffer, "dato: %d", nodo->dato);
outtextxy(x, y, buffer);
```

`sprintf` es como `printf`, pero escribe en un `char *`. Fijate la documentación de `sprintf` o `prinft` para ver las opciones que tenés para formatear la descripción de tu nodo.